# Expansion of universe effects on mass

Tags: mass, space-expansion, error-analysis, si-units, metrology

It has been noted that the metal alloy model previously used to characterize the value of 1 kilogram has been steadily increasing in mass due to unknown causes. Could this be a local effect of accelerating universal expansion with the increased velocity of expansion causing the noted increase in mass?

Comment: The kilogram has been redefined in a way that no longer uses a physical artifact.

Answer (score 1):

No it would not, for several reasons.

First, the expansion of the universe is manifest only on huge distance scales i.e., the typical distance between galaxies. If you scale it down to human distance scales, it is utterly undetectable.

Secondly, it progressively separates objects apart in space but it does not create more atoms inside those objects as it expands them.  This means that even if the expansion of the universe were causing the kilogram standard to expand, that expanded kilogram would weigh the same as it did before it got expanded.

Answer (score 0):

No. The expansion of space is actually a pretty tiny effect. It is $73$ km/sec/megaparsec. That is, two points $1$ megaparsec apart are separating by $73$ km/sec.

Or, two points $1$ parsec = $3.26$ light years = $3.08 \cdot 10^{13}$ km apart are separating by $73$ mm/sec = $0.16$ mph.

Or, two points $1$ km apart are separating by $2.37 \cdot 10^{-12}$ mm/sec = $7.5 \cdot 10^{-6}$ mm/year = 7.5 $\mu$m/millenium.

For reference, this last speed is about $10,000$ times slower than a glacier, or about $100$ times slower than continental drift.

The opposite sides of a $1$ kg mass are a few cm apart. So if making it bigger somehow makes it more massive, you would have to wait a very long time to see the effect.

But even that isn't happening. Chemical bonds aren't changing. They stay the same length. So the size of everyday objects stays fixed. And even if the mass expanded, that would not make it more massive. The number of atoms stays the same.

Answer (score 0):

As niels nielsen said, cosmology predicts no such effect.

But there's another reason it's unlikely that a universal physical effect was responsible for the mass drift: the drift was only detected by weighing the standard kilogram (IPK) against copies of itself. Many of the copies were made at the same time as the IPK, of the same alloy, so any change in fundamental physical laws would presumably affect them all in the same way, and we wouldn't have detected it.

[Wikipedia has an interesting section about the mass drift](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Prototype_of_the_Kilogram#Stability_of_the_IPK). You can see in the graph that most of the copies gained mass relative to the IPK, which suggests that the IPK actually lost some mass, but there's no way to be sure since we can't do new experiments on its past state.